# Using SQL Server variables in Java persistence session scope?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, session, scope

I'm pretty new to MS SQL Server with Java Hibernate persistence and I'm having some problems with the session scope. 
I know that SQL Server local (session) variable is scoped to a stored procedure or a batch where it was created.

But when I use persistence session like this:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
session.createSQLQuery( " declare @bit int; set @bit = 3; " ).executeUpdate();
List obj = session.createSQLQuery( " select @bit; " ).list();
```

It throws an error:

```
ERROR: Must declare the scalar variable "@bit".
```

And it turns out that each execution of `createSQLQuery( "..." )` creates a completely new batch.

My question is:

Is there any chance of using SQL Server variables (or temporary tables) in more than 1 execution of `createSQLQuery( "...")` from the same `Session` instance?
I would like to avoid creating database global variables as well as storing temporary, session data in some non-temporary tables.

Thanks in advance for any help!